# Regex string split with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split

(Javascript older version of Node.js)

Edit I have to clear up what I want.

I have multiple lines like these

```
var name1;

CONST    name2

   Let  nam;

leT     nam

  VAr n1  ;
```

My desired outputs are

```
name1

name2

nam

nam

n1
```

So I am trying codes like this.

```
/[^;]*/
```

But I need help because I have multiple patterns. Some may have semicolons/space/null after the variable names, I need to omit those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `/(?<=(var\s+)|(let\s+)|(const\s+))(\w+)/gim`

```js
let data = `
var name1;

CONST    name2

   Let  nam;

leT     nam

  VAr n1  ;
`;
data = data.match(/(?<=(var\s+)|(let\s+)|(const\s+))(\w+)/gim);
console.log(data); // [ 'name1', 'name2', 'nam', 'nam', 'n1' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp = /name[1-9]+/g`

```js
let arr = ['var person;', 'CONST    name2', '   Let  nam;', '  VAr n1  ;'];
var result = [];
for(var s of arr) {
    var split_array = s.replace(/  +/g, ' ').trim().split(' ');
    result.push(split_array[1].replace(';', ''))
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the name of the variable may be change, it won't be always 'name'

Comment: I think I made a mistake providing examples. name of the variable may change. Also, Var can be vAr

Comment: @NajeebTaher I update my answer with `split`

Comment: @YuTing I am sorry I had to update the question again to match complex spacing. Sorry

Comment: @NajeebTaher I update again with some of your test data.